# Modal body Text is displaying on VF page, not within the modal

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I'm tyring to do implement this modal on a VF page http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation and the issue is that the modal's body text is showing up on the VF page. It should obviously only be in the dialog. When I click on my button, the text shows in the dialog. How do I fix this?

Also, I have a second question, how do I get the buttons in the modal a single size?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"></link>


        <style>
            .value{
              background-color: #FCF7F7;
            }

            .ui-widget-header {
                background: #004386 !IMPORTANT;
                color: white;
            }


        </style>


    <script>

        $(document).ready( function (){


            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
               $(this).prop('value', true);
               $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('value', false).prop('checked', false);
            });

        });

         function atLeastOneIsChecked ()
         {                        
             if ( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0 ){
                 alert('Please select a secondary address if you wish to continue');
             }
             else
             {
                callApex();
             }

         }

         function createNewRecord()
         {
             $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height:300,
                  width:400,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    "Create new": function() {                        
                        CreateNewAF();
                       $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    },
                    "Cancel the Request": function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    }
                  }
                });
         }      
    </script>



    <apex:form >


    <apex:pageBlock  id="changeObjWrapperId" >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!cancel}" />        
                <input type="button" value="Create New record" class="btn" onclick="createNewRecord();" />
                <apex:actionFunction action="{!mySave}" name="CreateNewAF"/>

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Address Change">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>The new primary address will change the territory of this practitioner. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
         </apex:pageBlock> 

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this piece of code.

`$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, minWidth:450, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false, buttons: {Ok: function(){$( this ).dialog( "close" );}}});`
Add this code into `$(document).ready(function()` 
here you are passing auto open= false. and on your Javascript open this dialog just like

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
```

It will work for you

Comment: That's awesome! How do I make the buttons the same size?

Comment: @Niv Which button you are referring here. And what is the size.